# $scope variable value flicks in setInterval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, setinterval, flicker

Following is the code I used to Update my list count,
It work fine on count at first but as count changes the value flicks.
Ex : If count is 3 at first and then count is  updated as 4. The count variable flicks between 3 and 4.

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($scope.listing != undefined && $scope.listing != null) {
        $rootScope.countsData = $scope.listing.length;
    } else {
        $rootScope.countsData = 0;
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Format/indent your code, it is unreadable.

Comment: So when `count` is changed to 4, you still want to see 3? Why?

Comment: I don't want to see 3, But it is showing 3 and 4 both. I want to see only 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inject **$interval** to your controller and then change your code to this:

```
$interval(function() {
    if ($scope.listing) {
        $rootScope.countsData = $scope.listing.length;
    } else {
        $rootScope.countsData = 0;
    }
}, 2000);
```